# Show integral of function is positive definite

Tags: functions, control-theory, nonlinear-system, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

How would you prove that the integral of a function is positive definite, when you know that the function itself is positive definite?

i.e. prove
$ V(y) = \int_y^0 f_0(q) dq $ is positive definite given that $ f_0(y)$ is positive definite.

Think I'm missing some basic logic here so I'd appreciate an explanation.
Thanks!

Comment: @TeresaLisbon My apologies I should have clarified: yes positive definite as in f(0)=0 and f(x) > 0 for all x=/ 0.

Comment: Oh I see, this is the ODE sense. Actually, you should forgive me : you've used the right tags, so I'm the fool here! Having said that, $V(y)$ is differentiable, so at any extreme value of $V(y)$, we have that the derivative will be zero, but the derivative is $f_0$, so $V$ doesn't have extreme values except at $0$. This will probably be useful

Comment: I've also just realised that your statement need not be true unless you make $V(y) = \int_0^y f_0(y)dy$ for $y$ positive, and keep it like that for $y$ negative.

Comment: Try applying the fundemantel theorem of calculus.